# android application does not connect with firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

My android application does not connect with firebase.I used the tutorial in this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cab-p7pJBDw.Using gradle dependencies as stated in this tutorial gave an error.So I added the firebase-client-android-2.4.0 Jar file to the libs folder of the app and removed gradle dependencies.It cleared out the error and application runs fine.But it does not connect with firebase.Please help.

Comment: What error did the tutorial give? Are there any error messages in logcat? Without such basic information, it will be difficult to help.

Comment: logcat does not give any errors.The condition text field changes in the application when clicking  foggy and sunny buttons as in the tutorial.My problem is It does not change the condition in the firebase dashboard.Changing condition in the fire base dash board also does not change the condition text field in the app.Seems like app does not sync or connect with firebase.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the approach in the quickstart video is still correct. Can you share a minimal reproduction of your app, e.g. in a Github repo?

Comment: You are right.There has been no problem with the code.The problem has been with my internet connection.I was using a Wifi connection with proxy.When I switched on to a non proxy internet connection the app worked pretty fine.Now my problem is how to configure app to connect with the proxy connection.Thanks a lot for your consideration.